# Using the "WHERE" clause in SQL for Netsuite Saved Search

Tags: oracle, netsuite

How will I create the following formula in Netsuite Saved search:

```
 CASE WHEN 
         (SELECT {systemnotes.date} 
           WHERE {systemnotes.newvalue} = 'TC Client - TC Full') > 
             ( SELECT {usernotes.notedate} 
                WHERE {usernotes.notetype} = 'Appointment') 
                 THEN {internalid} END
```

The above formula returns Invalid expression.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to see as output and what is your full SQL query

Answer (score 0):

With NetSuite, it's not quite the same as how Oracle handles SQL for some reason...

CASE {systemnotes.newvalue} WHEN 'TC Client - TC Full' THEN CASE {usernotes.notetype} WHEN 'Appointment' THEN {internalid} END

This is more what you should be working towards.

I don't know the full story so this may not be fully correct.

Here's a good link to how NetSuite PLSQL is formatted...

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/

The standard CASE Statement is formatted like this :

CASE { expr WHEN comparison_expr THEN return_expr [ WHEN comparison_expr THEN return_expr ]... | WHEN condition THEN return_expr [ WHEN condition THEN return_expr ]... } [ ELSE else_expr ] END

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Mike, I tried the above formula but still doesn't work.